# Get App Version Number

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

How do you get the app version number? It's clear how to get OS version number etc, but nothing seems to be documented on getting the app version from the manifest?

Getting OS Version number works as such:

```
var VersionNumber = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
btn.Content = VersionNumber;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833354/how-to-get-app-version-in-windows-phone

Comment: Or see [How can I get my Windows Store app's title and version info?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371275/how-can-i-get-my-windows-store-apps-title-and-version-info), [Getting Application Version Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578663/getting-application-version-windows-phone-8). Please try to use the search and show what you have tried.

Comment: var obj = new AssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName); string sVersion = obj.Version;

Comment: @CodeCaster Search doesn't always show what you want http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+version+number+c%23+windows+phone+8.1

Comment: Your search is too specific (omit the version or only use major): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+version+number+c%23+windows+phone+8. And unfortunately every website's own search is worse than Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=get+version+number+c%23+windows+phone+8.1+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @timbaker, it does when you search using the correct tools https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=&hl=en-GB&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGLS_en-GBGB562GB562&q=c%23+windows+phone+get+application+version&gs_l=hp..0.41l916.0.0.0.5685...........0.

Comment: @MPatel Fair enough... Points taken. Though maybe its also worth noting that actually there some room for improvement there, rather than complaining at people who ask questions twice - reason why is not everyone uses Google and I would expect SO search to return something for that search if there was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Version from the manifest by loading the .xml like this:

```
string Version = XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml")
                    .Root.Element("App").Attribute("Version").Value;
```