# Retrieve the Current App version from Package

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-store, prism-storeapps

While I can get the assembly version using the following code

```
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var assemblyVersion = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

I would like to retrieve the Version from `Package.appxmanifest` in this case **1.0.0.4**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
  <Identity Name="zzz" Publisher="CN=zzz" Version="1.0.0.4" />
```

I expected to have access to `Windows.ApplicationModel`, but this is not available to me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my Windows Store app's title and version info?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371275/how-can-i-get-my-windows-store-apps-title-and-version-info)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Here's what you can do to retrieve the version in code:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

public static string GetAppVersion()
{
  Package package = Package.Current;
  PackageId packageId = package.Id;
  PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;

  return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);
}
```

Reference: http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_67.aspx

Comment: Perfect!   Cheers @Kevin!

Comment: @ChrisBallance you're welcome ! Always a pleasure to help a follow dev !

Comment: Do you also know how to retrieve the package description? Package.Current.Description is empty at runtime ...

Comment: app version is different when it is installed on xBox. do you know why?

Comment: Was not different on Xbox for me

Comment: If you're seeing different version on different platforms, double check that the package deployment is targeting those platforms. You'll see a row of checkboxes on the Packages step.