# Get app version from UWP (Windows 10) app

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

A simple question : How to get app version from C# code?

I want to send email from my UWP app and add into it app version to know which version user is using.

App version is stored on Package.appxmanifest, but i didn't want to make a xml reader to get it and i hope there is an esay way to do it.

Comment: Here's how I do it: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Templates%20(Project)/Minimal/ViewModels/SettingsPageViewModel.cs#L69

Comment: Thanks @JerryNixon-MSFT, my question is already asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635208/retrieve-the-current-app-version-from-package
So it's now marked as duplicated.