# Displaying version information of UWP application in App settings

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am building a UWP application. When I open the app settings for my App, I want to display the Version number of my application in the Specifications section.

For example- In the following image, you can see the version number as 1.2.4.0 under the Specifications section in the App settings. How can I do a similar thing for my UWP application.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdYU7.png)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please read this guidance and take action accordingly so we can either close or improve this question/answer for the benefit of the community:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: [Retrieve the Current App version from Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635208/retrieve-the-current-app-version-from-package)
That's how you can display it anyway.

```
        public string GetAppVersion()
    {

        Package package = Package.Current;
        PackageId packageId = package.Id;
        PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;

        return "Version " + string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);

    }
```

Comment: Any idea how you could set these values programatically?

Answer (score 2):

The [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit) has a [SystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/systeminformation) class which has many relevant properties and methods.

You could use it to get the information that you want.

For example,

```
// To get application's name:
public string ApplicationName => SystemInformation.ApplicationName;

// To get application's version:
public string ApplicationVersion => $"{SystemInformation.ApplicationVersion.Major}.{SystemInformation.ApplicationVersion.Minor}.{SystemInformation.ApplicationVersion.Build}.{SystemInformation.ApplicationVersion.Revision}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this for free, nothing special needs to be done. The App settings page will display the version number retrieved from your appxmanifest file.