# How to get the UWP(apps) target appversion programmatically?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created the UWP application. I have used some API which is available only in the latest version(19041, 17763) of UWP. I want to run in both pervious and latest version. So if I get the apps target version programmatically, I will check the condition which makes the app compatible for every versions. Is it possible to get the apps target version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the AppxManifest.xml file in the app installation folder. After that, you could load the xml file using [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument?view=winrt-19041). In the AppxManifest.xml, you could find a node called **TargetDeviceFamily** under **Package**->**Dependencies**, it contains a value called **MaxVersionTested** which is the value of the target version.

Here is the code snippet that you could check:

```
         var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("AppxManifest.xml");
        var xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
        var VersionText = xmlDocument.ChildNodes.LastOrDefault().ChildNodes.Where(p => p.NodeName == "Dependencies").FirstOrDefault().ChildNodes.Where(t => t.NodeName == "TargetDeviceFamily").FirstOrDefault().Attributes.GetNamedItem("MaxVersionTested").InnerText;
        MyTextBlock.Text = VersionText;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use powershell command to get version from file metadata (you must make sure your product have a valid value there)

and then you can use the following logic:
on path argument send path to app executable file (or dll) with file metadata updated field.

```
string GetVersion(string path)
{  
     var command = $"(Get-Command \"{path}\").FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion";
     var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
     {
            FileName = "cli",
            Arguments = $"/c powershell {command}",
            WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
      };
      var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
      p.WaitForExit();
      var fileVersion = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
      return fileVersion;
   }
```

This solution works well on local and remote targets..

if you need it locally only you can simply use **FileVersionInfo**  class and get it out of the FileVersion property

as given in MSDN example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get the file version for the notepad.
    // Use either of the two following commands.
    FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "Notepad.exe"));
    FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\Notepad.exe");

    // Print the file name and version number.
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + '\n' +
       "Version number: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion);
}
```

you can read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks for the code, Is this is the only way to get the target build version.

Comment: Edited and added another approach.

Comment: Hi @michael Gabbay, I have heard some Api's to get the target version like AnalyticsVersionInfo. I have tried out this but it doesn't give correct version. Is there any api like that to get the target version.

Comment: try see this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635208/retrieve-the-current-app-version-from-package

Comment: I need to get the targetsdkversion in which my uwpapp is running. For example, Im set my target version as **Windows 10, Version 1809(10.0 Build 17763)**, I need this target version programmatically.